# MSSQL 2008 SET IDENTITY INSERT on live database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, identity

I have a job that needs to update a table once a day using:-

`SET IDENTITY INSERT ON`

. However AT THE SAME TIME other users are using this live database and inserting records and this must be done using `SET IDENTITY INSERT OFF`.

Is there any way where the job can be run while still allowing the users to insert records?

Comment: Isn't that the other way around? Doesn't the jub requires `set identity insert on` while the user requires it to be off?

Comment: You are correct. The job requires identity insert ON while ongoing transactions require identity insert OFF.

Comment: "The job requires identity insert ON while ongoing transactions require identity insert OFF"  - that's a bit odd

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue for that.

The scope of Setting IDENTITY INSERT is `session`,

so if you used the next code:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName ON
Insert statement ...
```

other users mean other sessions so if they try inserting the identity, they will get the next error:-

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'TableName'
>   when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx/):-

> At any time, only one table in a **session** can have the IDENTITY_INSERT
>   property set to ON. If a table already has this property set to ON,
>   and a SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON statement is issued for another table,
>   SQL Server returns an error message that states SET IDENTITY_INSERT is
>   already ON and reports the table it is set ON for.

Comment: So some users can access the table using Identity_Insert ON while at the same time others can access the same table using identity_insert_off?

Comment: Yes, as MSDN Told us, its scope is session.

Comment: please use  sequence in your case.